# Call an javascript function and pass in callback function

Tags: javascript, flash

I want to call a javascript function in Action script, something like this:

```
ExternalInterface.call('a_js_function', param1, another_js_function);
```

I want the javascript function a_js_function takes in two params, one is a string, another one is a callback function. So I can call the js function like this:

```
function a_js_function(testStr, callback) {
    console.log(testStr);
    callback(testStr);
}

function another_js_function(str) {
    console.log(str);
}
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Problem solved, it turns out the second I passed in is a string, in javascript I have to turn string into function in order to call it.

Comment: Have you tried it? What results did you get?

Comment: @zzzzBov it's not calling another_js_function.

Comment: Any luck on the answers below?

Answer (score 0):

call like this

```
try {
       ExternalInterface.call('a_js_function', param1, another_js_function);
        } catch(e:Error) {
        trace(e)
        }
```

and for more information see [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#marshallExceptions)

Answer (score 0):

Since flash does not have any reference to the javascript function `another_js_function` you need to pass the function name as a string then access it using brackets on whichever namespace.  I used global variables for simplicity but it can be any object/namespace

```
another_js_function = function(testStr) {
    alert(testStr);
}

a_js_function = function(testStr, callback) {
    console.log( this.window );
    window[callback].call(this, testStr); // pass scope?
    // OR
    window[callback](testStr);
}
// Simulating call from Flash
a_js_function("howdy y'all", "another_js_function");
```

In Action: http://jsfiddle.net/3n1gm4/Np3bW/